# scss generates a css block when using extend and comment together

Tags: css, sass

I have the following scss (Sass <strike>3.2.12</strike> => 3.2.19 because of compass):

scss:

```
.text { 
  color: red;
}

.test1 {
  /* this causes the block to appear */
  p {
    @extend .text;
  }
}

/* no comment, no block */
.test2 {
  p {
    @extend .text;
  }
}
```

css:

```
.text, .test1 p, .test2 p {
  color: red;
}

.test1 {
  /* this causes the block to appear */
}

/* no comment, no block */
```

Any ideas on how to avoid the block containing only the comment?

Comment: If I put your code into sassmeister it doesn't give me that output. - http://sassmeister.com/gist/1974a7fc4767caead92f

Comment: That's not even semantically correct, is it? The `p` shouldn't spill out of the `.article`, right?

Comment: There's no way to get this output at all.  Sass won't generate empty blocks like that.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz It's fine in SASS/SCSS...he's just targeting any `p` inside an element with the class of `.article`.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I know, but that's not what the resulting CSS does, so it's not just a spurious empty declaration that does nothing, but _actively wrong_ output.

Comment: But it doesn't output the wrong CSS..at least not as far as I can tell...so there is something else going on. EDIT - Indeed there was see the 'answer' below.

Comment: do you guys think the 'answer' is bug or feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is a comment that I left in the article block.

Reproduced the problem and solution:

**http://sassmeister.com/gist/3116020d285be50b8807**

So the solution for now is to **remove comments from the block containing extends only**.

Don't know if that is a bug or feature. It still occurs in current sass 3.3.8

Comment: @cimmanon please explain why you mark my answer as not useful or unreproducible. It helps because it shows that blocks containing only extends will render if they also contain a comment which could be quite interestng for others, don't you think? There also is the sassmeister example that shows the problem and the solution. So it is reproducible.

Comment: also, there is no extra block rendered when sass compile options are set to 'compressed'

Comment: No, what is in your answer does not reproduce the problem as it is phrased in the question.  If your selector contains a comment it is not empty, now is it?  Sass renders it because it is not empty.

Comment: @cimmanon which is why I added a comment to the original question. now it is exactly that. But you do agree that the block containing only a comment is useless, even if there is 'something' in that block?

Comment: No, you have not modified the original question in such a way that this answer matches what is being asked.  Why would I think that a block that contains only a comment is useless?  If you think it's useless, then either don't put a comment in there or complain to the maintainers of Sass.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55841/discussion-between-markus-and-cimmanon).

Comment: I take a look at sassmeister to reproduce the problem. 
But there, the generated CSS looks a little bit different than yours. It keeps the Comment in the generated css.
Maybe it should report as an issue.

In my opinion its not wise to keep an CSS-selector if its only filled with an comment.

Comment: BTW- i opened an Issue, to stop these Discussion.
@Markus maybe you could change your Question a little, because of the difference to the Reproduced Problem on Sassmeister.

Comment: @pukoo where can we see the issue?

Comment: ok, the issue was closed by someone of sass, may its make sense to close these question, too.

https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1347